# Java's AtomicInteger equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I'm trying to replicate Android's [GenerateViewId()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#27291) to assign a unique Tag to dynamically created UIViews in Xamarin.iOS.

```
internal static class LayoutExtensions
{
    // A tentative to mimmic Java's AtomicInteger used by GenerateViewId()
    // https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#27291
    private static int nextViewTag = 1;

    internal static int GenerateViewTag(this UIView someView)
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            var result = nextViewTag;
            var newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF)
            {
                newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            }
            if (nextViewTag == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref nextViewTag, newValue, result))
            {
                return newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: The result of the CAS compared to the *current* `nextViewTag`, instead of to `result`. Is that intentional, and what does that mean?

Comment: I'm not sure. The Android method returns a boolean that tells if the sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet succeeded.

Comment: What is wrong with `Interlocked.Increment(int)`?

Comment: @HenrikHansen I would like to be as close as possible as the original Java implementation. May be this is irrelevant. This is why I opened this question in the first place.